# Is there a standard library with a generic reference interface?

Tags: java, generics, reference, pass-by-reference

I use a generic interface to define a reference for a given type `T`.  The purpose is to pass types by reference in method parameters.

```
interface Reference<T> {
   void set(T t);
   T get();
}
```

I quickly looked and didn't see anything like this in Google Guava.  Does anyone know of a library that defines this **interface** (likely along with the implementation)?  I am concerned finding an **interface** like below, **not an implementation.**  `AtomicReference` is an implementation and does not provide an interface.

Also note that I am not looking for a tool to generate getter/setter methods for class members.  The point of this is to pass method parameters by reference.

The reason I'm looking for an interface specifically is because I want to implement the interface in additional classes that provide additional behavior.  For instance, I might make a `PersistentReference` that extends `Reference` by adding a `save()` method.

If I found a published interface that was more widespread than my program, the hypothetical `PersistentReference` could then be used in classes that expect a `Reference` method parameter.

Comment: explain better what you would like to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thought: use the Guice [Provider interface](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Provider.html) and extend it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.concurrent.Future<T>` seems closest.

Comment: How so? I don't think I see the relation.